# Remote Desktop Connection to Windows has wrong keyboard layout

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, osx-mountain-lion, keyboard-layout

I'm running:

- OS X 10.8
- U.S. English as the default system language
- a German (Austrian) keyboard layout

Via RDP (specifically the Remote Desktop Connection client 2.1.1 from Microsoft), I'm connecting to:

- Windows 8
- German (Austrian) as the default system language
- a German keyboard layout (as seen in the screenshot)

  [image]

Unfortunately, the keyboard layout appears to be English in Windows, meaning, when I type <kbd>y</kbd> I get <kbd>z</kbd>, and when I type <kbd>-</kbd> I get a <kbd>/</kbd>, et cetera.

I assume the problem is on the Windows side of things, as I've never had issues before, even with RDP connections. Unfortunately, I have no idea what to change or what to tell Windows, since it *should* actually run just fine.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that despite the settings in the Windows Control Panel, another keyboard layout was set in the task bar:

[image]

Changing this back to *Deutsch (Österreich)* fixed the keyboard layout.